# Is there any paper/experiment on the deterministic behavior of coin-tossing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, stochastic-processes, determinism, randomness

I do not have background in Physics but Statistics. I am working on a small project on philosophy of probabilistic modeling.

Of course, we often model coin-tossing as if it comes from a Bernoulli distribution, but it is just a model that does not necessarily hold true in the real world even if how simple it is. I am searching for specific real-world papers/experiments demonstrating the deterministic behavior of coin-tossing given initial conditions.

For example, it could be an experiment which researchers controlled the environment (e.g. vacuum) , the force applied to each coin and other factors and built a rule to predict the outcome of tossing a coin based on initial conditions.

Probably, I can build a coin-tosser myself as I do have some Arduino boards, but it is too time-consuming, and it is hard (for me) to control for error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google [experimental coin tossing](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=experimental+coin+tossing) or something similar.

Comment: There have been some. For instance [this one](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/dyn_coin_07.pdf) is pretty well known.

Comment: Numberphile did a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYnJv68T3MM&ab_channel=Numberphile) on this.